# Group consecutive numbers from a list of numbers into a list of tuples using base python (NO itertools or more itertools allowed)

Tags: python, list, loops, group-by

I would like to turn a list like this:

`L1 = [3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14]`

Into a list of groups of consecutive numbers where each group is a tuple using base python (NO itertools or more itertools allowed).

Final list should look like this:
`[(3,), (5, 6, 7, 8, 9), (11,), (13, 14)]`

I came to this result by using `more_itertools`

```
import more_itertools as mit

[tuple(group) for group in mit.consecutive_groups(sorted(L1))]
```

Result:
`[(3,), (5, 6, 7, 8, 9), (11,), (13, 14)]`

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Surely you don’t expect other people to do the entirety of your work for you, right?

Comment: Also, is there any particular reason why you want/need the groups as tuples?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I couldn't even start cause of lack of experience and couldn't help myself with stackoverflow since I am new here as well. There is no particukar reason nor reasons why I should use tuples. I had a question and I had a result looking like I posted up in the message. I have reached the solution using more_itertools but thought to myself if I could only figure it out how to reach the solution using loops and control flow, I would be able to resolve quite a lot of simi.lar problems. Then I wanted to start and wasted hours and hours and no luck :DSo thank you for helping me!

Comment: Sounds good, hope you find the various answers informative! :)

Comment: I find various answers very informative so thanks a lot to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `generator` (`consecutive_groups` is generator):

```
L1 = [3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14]


def group_consecutive(l):
    r = []
    for e in l:
        if not r:
            r.append(e)
        elif e - r[-1] == 1:
            r.append(e)
        else:
            yield tuple(r)
            r = [e]
    yield tuple(r)


print(list(group_consecutive(L1)))  # [(3,), (5, 6, 7, 8, 9), (11,), (13, 14)]
```

Generator and using List slicing:

```
L1 = [3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14]


def group_consecutive(l):
    start = 0
    stop = 0
    for i, e in enumerate(l):
        if not stop or l[i] - l[i-1] == 1:
            stop += 1
        else:
            yield tuple(l[start:stop])
            start = i
            stop = i + 1
    yield tuple(l[start:stop])


print(list(group_consecutive(L1)))  # [(3,), (5, 6, 7, 8, 9), (11,), (13, 14)]
```

Comment: Instead of the `continue` in the first method, you could achieve the same thing by changing the second `if` to an `elif`, no?

Comment: @alexanderCécile True or combine the conditions with `or` like I did in the second method. Thanks for reminding me about elif I don't know why I forgot about it

Comment: You’re right, I hadn’t even noticed the possibility of using `or`!

Comment: thanks a lot for a great lesson.
I decided to disect the first generator solution by doing:

* Insert a line result = [] at the start of the function.
* Replace each yield expr with result.append(expr).
* Insert a line return result at the bottom of the function.
* Yay - no more yield statements! Read and figure out code.
* Compare function to original definition.


And managed to understand the logic and procedure. Many thanks.

Comment: Yes generators are a bit tricky the first time but they are so powerful when it comes to saving runtime memory

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14]


def consecutive_groups(l):
    if not l:
        return []
    current = [l[0]]
    for i, j in zip(l, l[1:]):
        if j - i == 1:
            current.append(j)
        else:
            yield tuple(current)
            current = [j]
    yield tuple(current)

print(list(consecutive_groups(l)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this solution, quite short and readable:

```
L1 = [3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14]

r, t = [], []
for i in L1:
    if t and i != t[-1] + 1:
        r.append(tuple(t))
        t.clear()
    t.append(i)
r.append(tuple(t))

print(r)
# [(3,), (5, 6, 7, 8, 9), (11,), (13, 14)]
```